# In codeigniter How to redirect after login using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, redirect

I have a login popup Modal. and i am logging through ajax

**Modal**

```
<div class="modal-body">
              <form action="<?php echo base_url('Login');?>" method="POST">
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email or Mobile*" value="" id="loginEmail" name="email" class="form-control input-feild">

                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password*" value="" id="loginPassword" name="password" class="form-control input-feild">

                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="button" id="l_submit" name="l_submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary input-feild">
                 </div>
               </form>
               <p id="error-msg"></p>
            </div>
```

I am trying to redirect after successful login using ajax. If email and password is correct then redirect to any page. If not then it will show the Error.

**Controller**

```
function index() {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
            echo validation_errors();

        }else {
                $email      = $this->input->post("email");
                $password   = $this->input->post("password");
                $user = $this->Perfect_mdl->check_user($email, $password);
                if ($user) {

                    $logged_in_data = array();
                    foreach ($user as $logged_in_data) {
                        $logged_in_data = array(

                                    'id' => $user[0]->id,
                                    'email' => $user[0]->email
                                );
                    }

                    $this->session->set_userdata($logged_in_data);
                    $id = $this->session->userdata('email');
                    $data['details'] = $this->Perfect_mdl->get_login_user_detail($id);

                    echo "Yes";

                }else {

                    echo "No";
                }
        }
    }
```

This is my controller in which i am checking login user email and password correct/incorrect.

This is my script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">  
        $("#l_submit").click(function(){

            var email  = $("#loginEmail").val();
            var password   = $("#loginPassword").val();

            $.ajax({
                url : "<?php echo base_url('Login');?>", 
                type: 'POST',
                data : {'email':email,'password':password},
                success: function(msg) {

                        if (msg == "Yes")
                           window.location.href = "<?php echo current_url(); ?>";
                        else if (msg == "No")
                            $('#error-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Incorrect Email & Password. Please try again ...</div>');
                        else
                            $('#error-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + msg + '</div>');
                    }
            });
            return false;
        });
</script>
```

As you can see in the success part, when i entered the correct email/password. It is showing Yes. But i want to redirect another page, Why this is showing **YES** on correct email/password.and On incorrect email/password This is showing **NO**.

Where i am Doing Wrong???

Comment: is it showing `YES` ?it should show Yes?please debug your code.did you check why `if (msg == "Yes")`  doesnt work?did you try to alert `((msg == "Yes"))` do some debugging

Comment: and if you are using ajax why do you submit form?may be you need to use submit fucniton not click

Comment: Yes i did but this is not showing me alert box when  `(msg = "yes")`

Comment: you should put it above the if condition

Comment: yes this is giving me alert after putting alert box above if condition.

Comment: what it shows?it should be `(msg == "yes")` not `(msg = "yes")`

Comment: yes you are right But what about my else condition , whether email/password is wrong it also going to the current url.. Now this is not checking else part ('msg' == "No")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change few lines of codes in jQuery and Controller function. Here I am attaching updated version of your code. Please refer below:

**View (Bootstrap Modal)**

```
<div class="modal-body">
          <form action="<?php echo base_url('Login');?>" method="POST">
             <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Email or Mobile*" value="" id="loginEmail" name="email" class="form-control input-feild">

             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password*" value="" id="loginPassword" name="password" class="form-control input-feild">

             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <input type="button" id="l_submit" name="l_submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary input-feild">
             </div>
           </form>
           <p id="error-msg"></p>
        </div>
```

This is your view file. It will remain same. On clicking on button you have written a script which need to be modified. Will attact after attaching controller's function:

**Controller**

```
function index() {
    if (!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        echo 'No direct script is allowed';
        die;
    }
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
        $result['status'] = 'error';
        $result['message'] = validation_errors();
    }else {
        $email      = $this->input->post("email");
        $password   = $this->input->post("password");
        $user = $this->Perfect_mdl->check_user($email, $password);
        if ($user) {
            $logged_in_data = array();
            foreach ($user as $logged_in_data) {
                $logged_in_data = array(
                    'id' => $user[0]->id,
                    'email' => $user[0]->email
                );
            }
            $this->session->set_userdata($logged_in_data);
            $id = $this->session->userdata('email');
            $data['details'] = $this->Perfect_mdl->get_login_user_detail($id);
            $result['status'] = 'success';
            $result['message'] = 'Yeah! You have successfully logged in.';
$result['redirect_url'] = base_url();
        }else {
            $result['status'] = 'error';
            $result['message'] = 'Whoops! Incorrect Email & Password. Please try again';
        }
    }
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode($result));
    $string = $this->output->get_output();
    echo $string;
    exit();
}
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#l_submit").click(function(){

    var email  = $("#loginEmail").val();
    var password   = $("#loginPassword").val();

    $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo base_url('Login');?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data : {'email':email,'password':password},
        success: function(resp) {

            if (resp.status == "success")
                window.location.href = resp.redirect_url;
            else
                $('#error-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + resp.message + '</div>');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

This is the correct answer. Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: This is not working for me it is showing undefined after login failed in error-msg

Comment: @vishalkumar Try to debug using **consol.log(resp);** before if condition like this:

`success: function(resp) {
      consol.log(resp);
            if (resp.status == "success")
                window.location.href = resp.redirect_url;
            else
                $('#error-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + resp.message + '</div>');
        }`

Comment: Yes i did but this is not showing any type of error or alert. i am not getting any type vaidation error ,

Comment: @vishalkumar Did you check your consol? It will show error if anything wrong with response. (I am considering you are using firebug)

Comment: Yes i did Still the validation error message is not showing. after adding the `console.log($resp)` i getting this in firebug  `Object { type: "error", message: "Incorrect Email/Password .....!" }` But  Why this is not showing any validation errors.

Comment: @vishalkumar got it: You need to parse the response you are getting. Then code will work

Comment: @vishalkumar got it: You need to parse the response you are getting. Then code will work

Comment: `$.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo base_url('Login');?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data : {'email':email,'password':password},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(resp) {

            if (resp.status == "success")
                window.location.href = resp.redirect_url;
            else
                $('#error-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + resp.message + '</div>');
        }
    });`


Use this one

Comment: i think this is pretty close  to the result  ` dataType: "json"`  But the validation error part is still the problem ...

Comment: @vishalkumar May I see screenshot of the issue you are facing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142441/discussion-between-vishal-kumar-and-abhishek-singh).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple `redirect()` (comes in the url helper) in your code if you want to jump to another controller/method from the script. However, this will not alert the user that the login was successful: it's just a plain redirect.

The proper way to do it would be returning a json file, so instead of echoing a yes or no, use this:

```
$response['type'] = 'error';
$response['msg'] = 'Login Succesful';
$response['redirect'] = 'http://your-url.com/controller/method';
echo json_encode($response);
die;
```

Then, you handle the answer in your ajax call, and some good alerting (in my case, Sweet Alert) kinda like this:

```
success: function(data) {
    if (data.redirect) {
        swal({
            title: '¡Success!',
            text: data.msg,
            timer: 2000,
            type: data.type,
            showConfirmButton: false
        }, function() {
            window.location.href = data.redirect;
        });
    } else {
        swal('¡Error!', data.msg, data.type);
    }
}
```

So what this code does is that if your json response has a redirect field, will trigger the redirection after a while. But if your json response does not have the field redirect, will just show an alert.

Answer (score 2):

Check your return data type. May be you can use in datatype in Ajax code. Return data can't read if condition. I am facing same problem or use this

if($.trim(msg) == 'Yes') {

Answer (score 1):

Change `echo "Yes";` to `die("Yes");`. This will make sure nothing will be sent after "Yes" or "No" and then the JS code will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Their is also a way to redirect from your controller after success.
In this case you just need to follow these two steps to redirect
This line in your controller where you get true condition and want to redirect

```
if($result){     
      echo base_url()."welcome/";  
    }  
    else{  
       echo 0;  
    }
```

on your html page where you applied your ajax, on true condition you try this to redirect page

```
success: function(result){  
            if(result!=0){  
                // On success redirect.  
            window.location.replace(result);  
            }  
            else  
                alert('wrong'); 
        }
```