# How to use submit form with ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I already make login form and success, but when I'm trying add ajax, it fails, does anyone know a solution? this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#formLogin").submit(function(e)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo site_url('login'); ?>",
            type:"POST",
            data:$("#formLogin").serialize()
        })
        .done(function(response)
        {
            if(response =='gagal')
            {
              $(".alert.alert-danger").show('fast');
            }
            else
            {
                window.location.href = "http://localhost/epeds_web/";
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault():
    });
});
```

Comment: No, nobody here knows a solution to a problem you haven't described.

Comment: Seems like your problem is almost same as [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43559783/in-codeigniter-how-to-redirect-after-login-using-ajax/43565461#43565461)

Please go through once

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In codeigniter How to redirect after login using ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43559783/in-codeigniter-how-to-redirect-after-login-using-ajax)

Comment: Your ajax URL is the controller where you are sending your data. You do not need the site_url. Just use URL: "Login/(method or function)"